# Ember model Not Bind Dynamically using Link-to

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember.js-2

I created an ember demo,A parent view and it's child
this is the parent view

```
<h1>A list of Todo Tasks</h1>
<ul>
{{#each model as |todo|}}
<li>{{#link-to "todos.details" todo}}{{todo.desc}}{{/link-to}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>

{{outlet}}
```

and Its js login is 
import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model (){
        return [{
            "id" : 1,
            "desc" : "Try use ember"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "desc" : "Add it to github"
        },
        ];

    }
});
```

but when i use the link-to and navigate the data didn't show unless i refresh the page
This is the child view

```
<h2>The Details for <span style="color: green;">{{model.name}}</span> is : </h2>
{{#if model.error}}
<p>{{model.message}}</p>
{{else}}
<ul>
 {{#each model.steps as |task|}}
    <li>{{task.do}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
{{/if}}

{{outlet}}
```

and its js logic

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(params){

        if(params.id == "1"){
            return {
                name : "Ember SetUp",
                steps : [{
                    id :1,
                    do : "Download Ember Cli"
            },
            {
                    id :2,
                    do : "Generate New Project"
            },
            {
                    id :3,
                    do : "Generate Pages&Routes"
            }
                ]
            };
        }
        else{
            return {
                error : true,
                name : "Not Found",
                message : "There is no task with this id"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

iam using ember 2.5 and this is part of the router

```
this.route('todos', function() {
    this.route('details',{path : "/:id"});
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{#link-to "todos.details" todo}}
```

Since you are providing the object `todo`, so it will not execute the model hook.
so try

```
{{#link-to "todos.details" todo.id}}
```

Refer here: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_dynamic-models

> Note: A route with a dynamic segment will always have its model hook
>   called when it is entered via the URL. If the route is entered through
>   a transition (e.g. when using the link-to Handlebars helper), and a
>   model context is provided (second argument to link-to), then the hook
>   is not executed. If an identifier (such as an id or slug) is provided
>   instead then the model hook will be executed.

Comment: thanks a lot Working pretty well, the thing is in this vid sending the object did execute the model hook.What is the diff ?
https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-define-models-for-routes-in-ember

Comment: That tutorial is little misleading, actually in that tutorial `todos.show` is showing the `todos` model not the `todos.show` model. since both are having the same data so we were not able to identify the difference.. Have a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/43f8ffc356603943d46a26360451f0ac?openFiles=routes.todos.js%2C&route=%2Ftodos%2F1) which demonstrate the issue

Comment: I got it, since the model in this tutorial is the same ember can figure out how to make a model hook , if not i should explicitly send the Id.

Answer (score 1):

Ack, OP of video here. Sorry about that. Small misspeaking on my part, I should address this in the comments of the video and try to revise that. Sorry for the confusion! D:

Comment: No problem @kumkanillam declare it well 
BTW I loved the fundamentals :D

Comment: @Abdoutelb Feel free to reach out to me via email with any more feedback, you can find a way to reach me through iheanyi.com or just DM me on Twitter! twitter.com/kwuchu